# How to create view or table from selecting all columns from multi join select statement?

Tags: sql, join, view, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a view or table (doesnt matter) from this statement:

```
select ms.*,fev.*,val.*
FROM table1 ms
    LEFT JOIN table2 fev
        ON ms.col1 = fev.col1
    LeFT JOIN table3 val
        ON val.col1 = ms.col1 
        AND val.date >= '2017-12-01'
```

I am trying to create the table this way:

```
select * into newtable

from (
 select ms.*,fev.*,val.*
    FROM table1 ms
        LEFT JOIN table2 fev
            ON ms.col1 = fev.col1
        LeFT JOIN table3 val
            ON val.col1 = ms.col1 
            AND val.date >= '2017-12-01'
) as newtable
```

why do I keep getting error:

```
The column 'abc' was specified multiple times for 'newtable'.
```

when I have specified table alias in the select statment?

Comment: Can you shoul the table1, table2 and table3?

You have that error because there is more than one column in those tables with the name 'abc', give different names to those columns.

Comment: many of the column names are same between the tables, however each table has hundreds of columns, so it will be tedious to list them all out. I was thinking there would be a more effiencent way to do joins using table name matches

Comment: @RustyShackleford hi, I know it's old but did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to name all of the columns rather than using a wildcard.

Any names common to the different tables will have to be aliased to make them different as all columns in the new view / table must be unique.

A quick way to grab all of the column names is to drag the columns folder from the object explorer into your script. I then like to replace ',' with '/n,'. You can then start aliasing the columns that are duplicated.

Comment: What table1 and 2 have the exact same column names why can’t the join just do it on the column name exactly?

Comment: Because the columns could have different data in. Table 1 and Table 2 could have a column called appointmentdate for example. But table 1 might have appointments relating to MOTs whilst table 2 has appointments related to Services. By itself, SQL Server has no idea what you might have put in the columns. There are applications like Clikview that will build you a related view based on column name matching, but SQL Server is working at the database level, so you have to specify which columns you want, and alias them so they are unique.